# Not able to drag and drop

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create drag and drop file uploader Demo.

Below is the js file :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var selectedFiles;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;
        var box;
        box = document.getElementById("box");
        box.addEventListener("dragenter", OnDragEnter, false);
        box.addEventListener("dragover", OnDragOver, false);
        box.addEventListener("drop", OnDrop, false);

        $("#upload").click(function () {
            var data = new FormData();
            for (var i = 0; i < selectedFiles.length; i++) {
                data.append(selectedFiles[i].name, selectedFiles[i]);
            }

            var data = {
                url: formatWebServiceURL("DefendantInfo.asmx", "ProcessRequest"),
                Parameter: data,
                callBackFunction: Test
            };
            ajaxformSubmit(data);
        });

    });

    function Test(result) {
        alert(result);
    }

    function OnDragEnter(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    function OnDragOver(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    function OnDrop(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        selectedFiles = e.dataTransfer.files;
        $("#box").text(selectedFiles.length + " file(s) selected for uploading!");
    }
</script>
```

and below is html code which is in a User control:

```
 <div style="text-align: center;" >
                        <div id="box">Drag & Drop files from your machine on this box.</div>
                        <br/>
                        <input id="upload" type="button" value="Upload Selected Files" />
                    </div>
```

The problem is whenever i try to drag files in the application it is not allowing me and showing below sign:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Browser tested which are not working : IE11, Firefox.

Browser tested which are working : Chrome

It is a browser issue

Comment: Here's a fiddle. Do you see the problem occurring there? Works for me in Chrome and Firefox. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/cf1dtzj7

Comment: It is working in Chrome and not working in Firefox and IE11. its a browser issue @isherwood

Comment: IE11 wants to open everything I drag in, so it's hard to say whether there's a code problem.

Comment: in my case it is showing not allowed sign as shown in image above @isherwood

Comment: See if you can modify the demo to replicate. Otherwise there's not much for us to look at.

Comment: yes thanks for help. i gurss something in code causing browser issue..